# How to read char as a number

Tags: c, scanf

This is really simply i know...

```
unsigned char var = 11;
...
fprintf(plik, "%c", var);
```

Then I want to read:

```
fscanf(plik, "%c", &var);
```

And the variable doesn't have the proper value. I tried `%d` but I had an error.

Comment: What is the input you want to read?

Answer (score 1):

A `char` is always a 8-bit number. `printf` will interprete is as an ascii char or an integer based on the format.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're asking. If you want to print the variable as the number 11 then simply:

```
printf("%d\n", var);
```

If you want to read it into an int then:

```
int a;
fscanf(plik, "%c", &a);
printf("%d\n", a);
```

If you are not reading the value correctly after writing it then maybe you want to fseek one position backwards.